# Pyspark Multiple Kafka Stream overwriting variables

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a pyspark program that can accept multiple Kafka streams mentioned in a config like so:

```
[stream1]
server=10.0.0.1:9090
topic=log_topic

[stream2]
server=10.0.0.2:9090
topic=file_topic
```

So my code uses the mentioned config to load multiple streams like this:

```
from configobj import ConfigObj
config = ConfigObj("my.conf")
for i, j in conf.iteritems():
    stream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, j['server'], "consumer_%s" % (i), {j['topic']: 1}).cache()
    stream.pprint()
```

Now say if stream1 has the following incoming contents:

```
aaaaa
aaaaa
aaaaa
...
```

and stream2 has the following contents:

```
bbbbb
bbbbb
bbbbb
...
```

Using pprint function, I was expecting to see the following output:

```
-----------------------------
2017-09-13 16:54:32
-----------------------------
aaaaa
aaaaa
aaaaa
...

-----------------------------
2017-09-13 16:54:32
-----------------------------
bbbbb
bbbbb
bbbbb
...
```

But I see the following output:

```
-----------------------------
2017-09-13 16:54:32
-----------------------------
bbbbb
bbbbb
bbbbb
...

-----------------------------
2017-09-13 16:54:32
-----------------------------
bbbbb
bbbbb
bbbbb
...
```

I understand that there seems to be lazy loading or something which is reading the variable `stream` after it has been read after the second iteration for the for loop. Can anyone let me know how to achieve this so that I can have the 2 separate streams in the for loop to process.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
streams = []
config = ConfigObj("my.conf")
for i, j in conf.iteritems():
    stream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, j['server'], "consumer_%s" % (i), {j['topic']: 1}).cache()
    streams.append(stream)

all_topic = ssc.union(*streams)    
all_topic.pprint()
```

Comment: Thanks Zhang for your reply. But I don't need the union of the streams, instead I want to apply different map reduce functions to both streams based on some logic. I need the streams separately.